# Validate input field upon blur

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to validate the field up on blur.

My code below does not work

Am I doing any mistake.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" jsf:id="create">                 
             <input type="text"                    
                   jsf:id="inputNo"
                   jsf:value="#{managedBean.number}"
                   jsf:required="true"
                   jsf:requiredMessage="Format is required">                   
                   <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_invalid_number" />
              </input>
              <h:message id="m_invalid_number" for="inputNo" p:class="error-msg"/>

     </div>
    <button jsf:action="#{managedBean.save()}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        Submit           
    </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: To exclude one and other, did you pay attention and love to browser's console and server's logfile? This question is answerable (and quite googlable) if you did see e.g. "Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined" in browser's console.

Comment: @BalusC. I have opened the console and there is no error. I also cannot find any logs. Would you help me

Comment: Sure, but the question is in its current form not answerable as there are too many probable causes which you did nowhere exclude. You didn't tell in technical terms what exactly failed, you just said "it doesn't work" as if you were the enduser instead of the developer. OK, next step is checking browser's HTTP traffic monitor. Is an ajax request actually sent? Is it in proper format? Did it return the expected response?

Comment: @BalusC. I have checked the traffic. The request is sent and in the response I get the message but no value in it. The expected response is not obtained. I also would like to mention that field is also validated by bean level validations.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem based on the information given so far in a blank playground project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions. So the cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. Perhaps you're nesting forms?